# Linux "rpl" command doesn't replace text

Tags: linux, replace, grep

I'm using `rpl` program in linux to replace `date(` with `pdate(` in some files.
But it says `A Total of 0 matches replaced in 1 file searched.` while grep output for `date(` is:

```
ariyan@ariyan-laptop:/var/www/moodle21$ grep -wR 'date(' admin/uploaduser.php
$today = make_timestamp(date('Y', $today), date('m', $today), date('d', $today), 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm using `rpl` as this:

```
rpl -wR 'date(' 'pdate(' admin/uploaduser.php
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Why use this weird `rpl` command and not a standard one like `sed`? `sed -i -e 's/date(/pdate(/g;' admin/uploaduser.php`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on rpl, but I think you'll have to drop the w option to be able to match `date(` since it's never enclosed in word boundaries on the line you found with grep.